# Is 'match /{document=**}' necessary in firebase security

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

This was my initial firebase security rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        match /users/{userId} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That didn't work. I kept getting an error telling me that I had insufficient privileges.

I changed it to the following and removed `match /{document=**}`.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /users/{userId} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
  }
}
```

That works, but my question is, was match `/{document=**}` necessary?  What exactly did that line do?

Comment: You will probably be interested in watching the following official video about Security rules: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`match /{document=**}` matches all documents in the entire database.  The wildcard there actually "gobbles up" the entire path of the document, for the purpose of further matchds.  You also nested `match /users/{userId}` underneath it, which doesn't actually have any meaning (as you can't nest more documents under an outermost document).

Your second example works, because you're matching users at the top level, not nested under anything else.

You typically only nest matches when you want to write one rule that matches documents in a collection, and another rule that matches documents in a subcollection of that one.  It can save a bit of typing.