# Firestore rules to read only one collection and rest of the database restricted

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So I have a project where I have some predefined rules already set which includes allow database read if user is authenticated and then allow some seperate stuff which i don't know much but when i integrated stripe in my firebase then stripe asked me to add those in my firestore rules.

Now i want to allow everyone to read from one specific collection and its one subcollection but i am not being able to do that

Before my rules were this

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if
          request.auth != null;
    }
  }
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{uid} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == uid;

      match /checkout_sessions/{id} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
      }
      match /subscriptions/{id} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == uid;
      }
    }

    match /products/{id} {
      allow read: if true;

      match /prices/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
      }

      match /tax_rates/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After they are these

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.auth != null;
    }
     match /organization/{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;     
    }
  }
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{uid} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == uid;

      match /checkout_sessions/{id} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
      }
      match /subscriptions/{id} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == uid;
      }
    }

    match /products/{id} {
      allow read: if true;

      match /prices/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
      }

      match /tax_rates/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But none of them are allowing users to read the organization collection publically

This is my database with some collections and i only want `organization` + organization's subcollection `campaign` to be publicly available.

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between your before and after rules? I find them same. And what I think is you want to set Firestore rules so that everyone can read only a specific collection and subcollection while the rest of DB is restricted for them, but at the same time I am confused about the last line you wrote But none of them are allowing user to read the organisation collection publicly. Kindly explain.

Comment: Sorry i added wrong screenshot kindly check now

Comment: Can you please edit the question again and give me the structure of your firestore database including what all collections -> documents -> subcollections -> documents. Also replace the screenshots of your file by copy pasting your rules that way it is easier to debug.

Comment: Edited it all can you please check now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your rules :**

```
rules_version = '2'; 
service cloud.firestore { 
match /databases/{database}/documents { 
match /{document=**} { 
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
 } 
match /organization/{document=**} { 
allow read: if true; 
} } 
match /databases/{database}/documents { 
match /users/{uid} { 
allow read: if request.auth.uid == uid; 
match /checkout_sessions/{id} {
allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid; } 
match /subscriptions/{id} { 
allow read: if request.auth.uid == uid; 
} 
} 
match /products/{id} { 
allow read: if true; 
match /prices/{id} { 
allow read: if true; 
} 
match /tax_rates/{id} { 
allow read: if true; 
} } } }
```

**Rules modified that works :**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /organization/{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;     
    }
   
    match /users/{uid} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == "priya";
        }
      match /checkout_sessions/{id} {
        allow read : if request.auth.uid == "priya";
        allow write: if request.auth.uid == "priya";
      }
      match /subscriptions/{id} {
        allow read : if true;
      }
      match /products/{id} {
      allow read: if true;
    }
      match /prices/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
      }
      match /tax_rates/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
      }
    }
  }
```

**Explanation :**

1. I have removed the :

   ```
   match /{document=**} { 
   allow read, write: if request.auth != null; }
   ```

   `match /{document=**}` matches all documents in the entire database.
   The wildcard there actually "gobbles up" the entire path of the
   document, for the purpose of further matches. You also nested `match /organization/{document=**}` underneath it, which doesn't actually
   have any meaning (as you can't nest more documents under an
   outermost document). My rules work because I am matching the
   organization collection at the top level, not nested under anything
   else.

   **Source** :

   https://stackoverflow.com/a/55719394/15803365
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#default_rules_locked_mode
2. I have changed :

   ```
       match /organization/{document=**} { 
           allow read: if true;



   To 

       match /organization/{org}/campaign/{document=**} {
             allow read: if true;     
           }

   As you specified, you only want organization + organization's
   subcollection campaign to be publicly available.  I have designed a
   Firestore security rule that allows only documents and
   subcollections inside your campaign sub collection to have public
   read access. If you try to give documents under organization
   collection public read access, it will be denied. As the public read
   access only applies to documents/subcollections under campaign sub
   collection which is under organization collection, If you want any
   collections/documents inside organization to have public read
   access, you can change this to 

   match /organization/{document=**}{ 
       allow read: if true;  }
   ```

   **Source :**

   https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards
3. `match /databases/{database}/documents` {

   ```
   This was a duplicate/ repeat of the first
   /databases/{database}/documents and it pretty much means matching to
   the default database we have and it's where all our Firestore rules
   should be inside.  Creating another /databases/{database}/documents
   is not correct and does not make sense.
   ```

   **Source :**

   https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#overlapping_match_statements

You should test your rules, using the **Firestore Simulator**. The above rules were checked and modified following this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjI4vdmZ7UU&t=579s)

**How to test the rules?**

**Open your Firebase Console. Go to Firestore Database, Click on Rules tab as highlighted in this screenshot. Click on Rule Playground and here you can simulate and test your rules.**

If you are checking for **public read access**, change the simulation type to **‘get’**, specify the exact location path for which you want to check the rule in Location field for eg. subscriptions/{id} for your match /subscription/{id} rule. Set **Authentication to off**. Run the simulator by clicking on Run button and you will get a green/red message specifying your rule was tested successfully/denied respectively.

[image]

If you are checking for **authenticated read access**,  change the simulation type to **‘get’**, specify the exact location path for which you want to check the rule in Location field .For eg. users/{uid} for your match /users/{uid} rule. Set **Authentication to on**. Specify the Firebase uid, email, name, phone number with some random values. Run the simulator by clicking on Run button and you will get a green/red message specifying your rule was tested successfully/denied respectively. Here you have to keep in mind that request.auth.uid should be equal to uid. As we are testing it on a simulator, we hard code the values in uid, as request.auth.uid is already set when we give value to Firebase uid. When in production, you can set uid in your application.

[image]

If you are checking for **authenticated write access**,  change the simulation type to **’create’**, specify the exact location path for which you want to check the rule in Location field .For eg. checkout_sessions/{id} for your match /checkout_sessions/{id} rule. Set **Authentication to on**. Specify the Firebase uid, email, name, phone number with some random values. Run the simulator by clicking on Run button and you will get a green/red message specifying your rule was tested successfully/denied respectively. Here you have to keep in mind that request.auth.uid should be equal to uid. As we are testing it on a simulator, we hard code the values in uid, as request.auth.uid is already set when we give value to Firebase uid. When in production, you can set uid in your application.

[image]

Comment: Didn't work. So i have 5 collections (users, products, metaData, organization and Causes) users have a lot of subcollection of which checkout_session and subscription permission are given to me by stripe also with products it has prices and provided by stripe. Now i don't want to change permission for those also rest of the database can be red by any auth user but now i only need to give one more access in which i want to give organization and its campaign access to everyone.

Comment: Can you please help me with this

Comment: Yes sure. Let me take a look at your comment

Comment: If you want your organization collection and its full path including its documents and subcollections 'campaign' to have the public read) just try : match /organization/{document=**}{ 
    allow read: if true;  } like you initially did but only with how I have given in my answer. I am editing my 'Rules modified that works'. Just have a look and copy that and try.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked finally also I am running into another issue which is to how to create a rule for indexed subcollections. In my case the campaign subcollection is indexed so i can fetch this collection directly without knowing its parent collection so i want to know how can i set rule for that

Comment: Glad that it worked! This question already has so many comments, I would like to answer this separately so it would be nice if you open a new question on how to create rules for indexed subcollections. I will assist you there. Thanks!